# How to read the data from a file which is starting with "." using expect

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, expect

I am finding the difficulty in reading the data from a file using expect.

The following i tried

```
set f [open "/.abc"]
set pqr [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
```

There is only one line in the file and I am trying to read the same.

But getting the out put

```
couldn't open "/.abc": permission denied
    while executing
"open "/.abc""
    invoked from within
"set f [open "/.abc"]"
```

I have tried to change the permission as well using `chmod 777` but still getting the same output.

Comment: is this file located in the root (`/`) directory? if not, just drop the `/`

Comment: yes this file is in root directory /root/.abc and I found chmod 777 /root/.abc worked without any issue. but when doing set f [open "/root/.abc"]  getting permission denied

Comment: do you have execute permission on `/root`?

Comment: ok now I copied the file from root to tmp and trying to read from there , using set f [open ".abc"] from tmp dir itself, but now getting "no such file or directory" even i can see the file is available there.

Comment: if you moved the file to `tmp` you should use `set f [open "<path>/tmp/.abc"]` or you could try to enter into directory before then command addinf `cd <path>/tmp` then command `set...` then `cd -`